# HighCharts(LineCharts) X-Axis elements mingled one another

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Iam having more number of elements for the x-axis in the highchart ,the problem is as show in the below image

[image]

see the x-axis value..how can i resolve it ..is there any solution

Comment: Use Rotated X Axis Lables

Comment: xAxis: {categories: [Print your these comma separated values ] }

Comment: rotated axis labels is very often a bad idea.  I would take a good look at whether you actually need every label there.  If you do, you do, and rotation is certainly an option.  In MOST cases, you don't, and the usability of the chart will be enhanced by removing unneeded labels and avoiding rotation.  FWIW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Rotated X Axis Labels.

```
xAxis:{
                            labels: {
                                align:'right',
                                style: {
                                      cursor: 'pointer',
                                      fontSize: '11px',
                                      fontWeight:'bold'
                                },
                                rotation:300, 
                            } 
                        },
```

See Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/uZaWz/12/